# List of ints input to ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I've values that need to be added into a ArrayListbecause they have to be connected to each other and at the same time needs to be removeable. the contraption in my head is somewhat similar to naval battle. I've boxes that needs to be clicked. when you click one of them right the box turns green. when you clicked all of the pared boxes they turn into golden boxes.

my question is: is there a more smooth and easy going wat to add the values below to a ArrayList? I've tried some forloops but all didnt work;

```
ArrayList[][] Boxes = new ArrayList[6][];
  
   Boxes[0][0].add(1110);
   Boxes[0][1].add(1210);
   Boxes[0][2].add(1310);
   Boxes[0][3].add(1410); 
   
   Boxes[1][0].add(2110);
   Boxes[1][1].add(2210);
   Boxes[1][2].add(2310);
   
   Boxes[2][0].add(2121);
   Boxes[2][1].add(2221);
   Boxes[2][2].add(2321);
   
   Boxes[3][0].add(3110);
   Boxes[3][1].add(3210);
   
   Boxes[4][0].add(3120);
   Boxes[4][1].add(3220);
   
   Boxes[5][0].add(3130);
   Boxes[5][1].add(3230);
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement ArrayList of ArrayList?

Comment: When you have logic to this a good idea is to create a class for it, so wrap your pair of boxes into a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide a helper method to build array of lists, the initialization may be compacted:

```java
// warning about rawtypes
private static ArrayList[] buildArrayOfLists(Integer... arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
                 .map(i -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(i)))
                 .toArray(ArrayList[]::new);
}

// usage -- warning about rawtypes
ArrayList[][] boxes = new ArrayList[][] {
      buildArrayOfLists(1110, 1210, 1310, 1410),
      buildArrayOfLists(2110, 2210, 2310),
      buildArrayOfLists(2121, 2221, 2321),
      buildArrayOfLists(3110, 3210),
      buildArrayOfLists(3120, 3220),
      buildArrayOfLists(3130, 3230)
};

Arrays.stream(boxes)
      .map(Arrays::toString)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[[1110], [1210], [1310], [1410]]
[[2110], [2210], [2310]]
[[2121], [2221], [2321]]
[[3110], [3210]]
[[3120], [3220]]
[[3130], [3230]]
```

**Update**
In order to get rid of warnings about using raw types for `ArrayList[][]` and use general `List` instead of specific implementation, it is possible to refactor the method and its usage in a more typesafe and warning-free way:

```java
private static <T> List<?>[] arrayOfLists(T... arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
                 .map(i -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(i)))
                 .toArray(List<?>[]::new);
}

// usage - no warning about rawtypes, explicitly suppress unchecked
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Integer>[][] safeBoxes = (List<Integer>[][]) new List<?>[][] {
      arrayOfLists(1110, 1210, 1310, 1410),
      arrayOfLists(2110, 2210, 2310),
      arrayOfLists(2121, 2221, 2321),
      arrayOfLists(3110, 3210),
      arrayOfLists(3120, 3220),
      arrayOfLists(3130, 3230)
};
```

Comment: thanks, This is the way I was hoping to structure it